# Modify map attribute in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I need to update one parameter from a object, the awslogs_group parameter should be appended (eg. foo-bar)

```
variable "task_log_drive" {
  default = {
     log-drive = "awslogs"
    options = {
      awslogs_group = "foo"
      awslogs_stream_prefix = "foo"
      awslogs_create_group = "true"
      awslogs_retention_period = "7"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using the following local variable to handle.

```
locals {

modified = merge(var.task_log_drive, { options = {awslogs_group = "${var.task_log_drive.options.awslogs_group}-bar"}})

}
```

But, when i merge them, the function works, but rest of the parameters are lost

```
{
  "log-drive" = "awslogs"
  "options" = {
    "awslogs_group" = "foo-bar"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE: with @Marcin help i reach the result doing this:**

```
modified  = merge(
                var.task_log_drive, {options = { awslogs_group = "${var.task_log_drive.options.awslogs_group}-bar"
                   awslogs_stream_prefix = "${var.task_log_drive.options.awslogs_stream_prefix}",
                   awslogs_create_group = "${var.task_log_drive.options.awslogs_create_group}",
                   awslogs_retention_period = "${var.task_log_drive.options.awslogs_retention_period}",
                }})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go one level deeper:

```
modified = merge(var.task_log_drive.options,  {awslogs_group = "${var.task_log_drive.options.awslogs_group}-bar"})
```